# Should I use cross validation or validation dataset?

Tags: machine-learning

I have the dataset of 9 classes and 3000 images approx.
Should I use cross validation for deep (4 conv layers, 4 max pool, 2 fc, 2 dropouts and softmax) convolutional network in such conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably yes, because the amount of images per class, isn't that much. Specially when you create a train-test-validation set : 70-15-15% ? Thus hypothetically, if you train your classifier on 70% of your dataset and your data-set is equally divided over the classes. Then each (training) class will contain +/- 3000*0,7 = 2100 /9 = 233 images...

Also a great motivation to use cross validation is, is that you'll generalize the classifier more. (+ The amount of training examples will be technically higher)